# Else if not working correctly when scanning file

Tags: java, file, if-statement, do-while

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Coursework2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException { {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader("seats.txt"));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        double defaultdiscount = 17.5, discount = 16.97;
        boolean random = true;
        while (random) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your Surname:");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Good morning, Manager "  + name + " Would you like to apply a specific discount rate?");
        String decision = scan.nextLine();


        if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || decision.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("That's great, Mananger " + name + ".");
            System.out.println("How much discount would you like? (1-100)");
            break;
        } else if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("no") || decision.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("Alright, " + name + " Here's all the seats without discounts:");
            //break;
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid Input, please try again. Restarting.");
        }
        
        discount = scan.nextDouble();
        defaultdiscount = discount;
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String table = reader.next();
        double price = reader.nextDouble();
        int bookings = reader.nextInt();
        
        double newdiscount = (((price/100.00*discount)*bookings));
        double newincome = (price*bookings-(((price/100.00*discount)*bookings)));
        System.out.printf("Seat type: %s, Price: £%.2f, Bookings: %d %n",table, price, bookings );
        System.out.printf("Discount: £%.2f, Income: £%.2f %n", newdiscount, newincome);
        
        String decision;
        do {
            System.out.printf("Seat type: %s, Price: £%.2f, Bookings: %d %n",table, price, bookings );
            //decision = scan.nextLine();
            decision = scan.next();
        }
        while (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
        System.out.printf("Seat type: %s, Price: £%.2f, Bookings: %d %n",table, price, bookings );
        }
        
        reader.close();
        scan.close();
        }
    
    }
}
```

I understand that the code runs sequentially, but when it comes to trying to run the read files through the else if (No), it can't go above the while reader or inside the else if or it won't see the info from the text file, and when outside, it can't see the variables. I'm just a bit confused. It feels like something might be in the wrong place and I can't wrap my head around it.

I've given this a go, using the correct comparisons, and declaring the string inside of the while. But I'm still getting some errors. I'm thinking maybe setting the string to "null" isn't the correct way of resetting, since I've already declared it has a scan.nextLine previously?

Comment: You mention errors, but do not show any

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: If the answer has been found, accept it/upvote it, but please don't vandalize your posts; that's making more work for the moderators where none needs to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the if statement like this

```
while(random){
    if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || decision.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        System.out.println("That's great, Mananger " + name + ".");
        System.out.println("How much discount would you like? (1-100)");
           random = false;
   }
    else if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("no") || decision.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        System.out.println("Alright, " + name + " Here's all the seats without discounts:");
        random = false;
               }
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid Input, please try again. Restarting.");
}
```

You will not loop it if you never change "random" boolean to false. Also, try not using break in this case.
Also, try creating the variable "name" and "decision" outside the loop, as good practice. You should also rename "random" to something like "isBadAnswer"